# How to pass parameters to a Flash projector (Windows)?

Tags: flash, flashvars, projector, embedded-flashplayer

Is there any way to pass command line parameters to a Flash projector in Windows?  I have another application (in this case, an installer) that will need to communicate to a Flash projector (the same way flashvars work).  I wasn't able to find any information online (everything seems to be focused on using FSCommand parameters for executing future projectors, which doesn't help me with calling the original one)...

Comment: If you want to hack in some simple communication, you can store to clipboard.  This easily gets into a mess for large projects, though.  You could also use flash's net.sockets, but that would require you to write a custom server to send a policy file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that standard Flash projectors can not do this. However, other third party wrapper's such as MDM's Zinc or NorthCode's SWFStudio may offer that functionality.

Answer (score 11):

just a note on this. you can pass parameters to the standalone flash player. i created a .bat file like this, which works like a charm:

```
flashplayer_10_sa.exe aFlashFile.swf?param=value?otherparam=othervalue
```

you can download the standalon player from adobe:
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: This is excellent - I didnt find this tip anywhere else and I've been looking for some time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @thalm Shouldn't that be aFlashFile.swf?param=value&otherparam=othervalue

Answer (score 4):

If you have the file served behind an HTTP server, let's say **http://domain.com/main.swf**, you can choose the option Open URL from the projector and pass the **flashvars** along with the URL like so:

```
http://domain.com/main.swf?var1=value1&var2=value2
```

Comment: I wish that had been a possibility.  The project I was working on was for a CD-ROM installer for enterprise customers, so we couldn't assume they had internet connectivity...

Comment: You could also do something like:

file:///C/Users/User/Desktop/main.swf

Probably would have also worked. :)