# How to pass flashvars to standalone flash player

Tags: flash

Is it possible to pass flashvars to standalone flash player via the commandline? Among other reasons, I want to run some unit tests from the command line.

I have done some Google searches, the question has been asked before but no answer that I can find.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to a Flash projector (Windows)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089578/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-flash-projector-windows)

Answer (score 17):

Yes, I figured this out today(Say you have a flashvar called "p"):

flashplayer.exe "file://c:\myswf.swf?p=100"

Works for the linux flashplayer too...

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass command-line parameters to an .exe projector.

Alternatively, you might want to wrap your .swf on another, and have the wrapper load it with parameters, like this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("your_cool_app.swf");
request.data = "a=1&b=2"
loader.load(request);
```

Comment: What does "Try to pass command-line parameters to an .exe projector" mean? "./flashplayer foo.swf?qux=baz" doesn't work. Thanks for the second suggestion, though less than ideal (I have to write a new swf for every change parameters) I may be able to make it work in my case.

Comment: It means publish it as an .exe executable, and run it in the command line with parameters.

Comment: This isn't a real answer.

Comment: The answer functions, now I can load the variable at the another SWF with this sentence: [code]Object(root).loaderInfo.parameters.variable_name + "";[/code]